# RegEx Parsing in Excel or VBA script to separate text into two rows

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a cell that has Latitude and Longitude coordinates in three different forms.  Content within the cells looks like this:

> 35°21′N 81°47′W / 35.35°N 81.79°W / 35.35; -81.79 (Ellenboro (Jan. 11, EF2))
>   38°46′N 85°28′W / 38.76°N 85.46°W / 38.76; -85.46 (Madison (Jan. 17, EF0))
>   etc.

I want to extract only the last set of numbers (35.35; -81.79) and put each one in a different row, one for latitude and one for longitude.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Split() on `/`, take the last element of the resulting array and split that on `(` - take the first element of that array and split on `;` - the resulting array has your values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy just with using **formulas** - here's my solution (assuming original strings are placed in column A starting A2):

1. B2 (Latitude): `=TRIM(MID($A2,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/","@",2))+1,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,";","@"))-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/","@",2))-1))`.
2. C2 (Longitude): `=TRIM(MID($A2,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,";","@"))+1,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"(","@"))-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,";","@"))-1))`.
3. Autofill down both formulas as you need.

This will return results as **strings**. If you want them as **numbers** - just add `=VALUE(...)` wrapper to each formula. However, my local setting use **comma** as decimal separator, so I must add one more `SUBSTITUTE` for handling this.

For your convenience sample file is shared: https://www.dropbox.com/s/twkcln8lozdgga9/CoordsSplit.xlsx

Comment: Perfect.  I didn't realize formulas would be effective for this, so that's why I requested RegEx.  Thanks

Comment: @Parseltongue Happy to help!) Frankly, my "code" does exactly as Tim Williams mentioned in the comment to your request.

Answer (score 0):

Start by replacing:

```
\s+\(.*
```

by the empty string. Then replace:

```
^.*/\s+
```

by the empty string. You will then only be left with the last set of numbers, splitting them is then easy (with `\s*;\s*`).

Demo in perl:

```
$ perl -ne 's,\s+\(.*,,; s,^.*/\s+,,; my @coords = (split(/\s*;\s*/)); print "Latitude: $coords[0]; longitude: $coords[1]"' <<EOF
> 35°21′N 81°47′W / 35.35°N 81.79°W / 35.35; -81.79 (Ellenboro (Jan. 11, EF2))
> 38°46′N 85°28′W / 38.76°N 85.46°W / 38.76; -85.46 (Madison (Jan. 17, EF0))
> EOF
Latitude: 35.35; longitude: -81.79
Latitude: 38.76; longitude: -85.46
```